# phpMyAdmin Access Denied #1045 using xampp

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, access-denied

I'm using `xampp v3.2.2`, and when I start the server `Apache`, i try going to `localhost/phpmyadmin/`  but i get 3 messages:

> 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

and

> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

And that `phpmyadmin` tried to connect the `MySQL` server and the server denied that connection, that I should check the `host`, `username` and `password` on `config.inc.php`

I've searched on the internet but nothing has been useful.

Here's config file code:

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code for people to look at?

Comment: Sorry, what code?

Comment: The config file you are using to connect with.

Comment: update your original comment so its with the questions please. Also use the code option.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same xampp version, the only difference in my config file that differs from your several settings listed above [not changed by me, came as-is] is this setting:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

Also, see some of the "Related" links located to the right-hand side of the page, as some information in those may also have relevance should there be other issues.

Comment: Yes, I used to have that in 'host' but i read that i should put it on localhost, because I was having the same problem